# Google Application Credential error clod sql proxy

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys, cloud-sql-proxy

I have created a PostgreSQL cloud instance with public ip. I have added my home ip into whitelist.

I have installed the cloud proxy SQL like Google doc.

When I run the proxy, I get this error:

> The proxy has encountered a terminal error: unable to start: failed to get instance
>
> private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated

The error seams refer to credential json key ID client OAuth 2.0

Can you help me to understand this error and how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need a service account key file that is a bad practice. Remove it, remove the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var and perform a gcloud auth application-default login to use your user account to be authenticated. In addition, Cloud SQL proxy will open a secure channel even if your personal IP is not allowed. My recommendation: set a public IP, but remove all the authorized network. It's also a a bad security practice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated` is only concerned with the `private_key` field, rather than json in which it is contained. So it seems the key text might be mangled in some way.

You can follow this documentation how [Connect to your Cloud SQL instance using SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl), then you can follow this guideline how to [Configure SSL/TLS Certficates](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance#client-certs), and [Connect using a MYSQL client](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#local), you can follow this and try.

or

You can follow the directions here [Create and manage service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys), could you perhaps remake a keyfile following these instructions.